# Videos with lots of English dialogues for a 2 - 3 year old child

Tags: discussion

Intention is to teach the child (2 - 3 years old) spoken English.

I do NOT want shows like **Tom & Jerry** since there are no
dialogues.

I found that the child found **Finding Nemo** to be too slow
for her.

Which English shows with **lots of English dialogues** and
moving/interactive cartoons or children or animals would
you recommend for a 2 - 3 year old child?

Comment: [Sesame Street](http://www.sesamestreet.org/)? Does it have to be animated?

Comment: @Catija I stated animated because I think that the child will not be interested in a show where there is a person sitting on a chair and giving a lecture in English. My point was that something should be moving.

Comment: There are hundreds of live-action shows for kids... people don't generally lecture 2-3 year olds. Sesame Street is a combination of live-action, puppets, and animation. I grew up on it and loved it a lot.

Comment: @Catija Thanks. Can you list some other shows too, and write an "answer"?

Comment: in the U.S., your best bet would be television shows aimed at children and broadcast on PBS. While they don't have a monopoly on quality kids' programming, most of their offerings do have an educational slant.

Comment: Be careful―children don't generally learn language from television, and allowing more than a couple hours a day of television has been shown to slow language development.  Children under 2 years old shouldn't be shown television at all.  They need real human beings to learn languages.

Comment: You might take a look at [**The Electric Company**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Electric_Company) which was a US educational series during the 1970's, if you can find the episodes. Your child may be a bit young for this, as it primarily teaches reading and grammar usage. But being directly English learning related, I would definitely keep it in mind.